# ipcRenderer listeners in multiple js files for one renderer process/main window not being called

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

Building an electron app with plain js. I got a single mainWindow with a single webContents (checked with webContents.getAllWebContents()). In the main window I have two different files, one that is loaded from the start (`mainWindow.js`) and one that is loaded dynamically (`customerList.js`).

So, from the main process I am running `mainWindow.webContents.send('customer:display', customerObject);`. Then in `customerList.js` I have

```js
const customerElectron = require('electron');

customerElectron.ipcRenderer.on('customer:display', (e, customer) => {
  console.log('customer: ', customer);
};
```

This is not being called. To check, if it was called, I added the same to my `mainWindow.js`:

```js
const mainElectron = require('electron');

mainElectron.ipcRenderer.on('customer:display', (e, customer) => {
  console.log(customer, 'customer');
};
```

This is being called and logs the right customer object. Since there is only one webContents I would assume that ipcRenderer just adds the event to that. Also, I checked if the event was added by wrapping the listener in `console.log(JSON.stringify(customerElectron.ipcRenderer))`. Before the listener was created, it had 0 events, afterwards it had 1 events. So the code for adding the listener is definitely called.

Since the js script belongs to dynamically loaded content and currently needs to be loaded after the content is loaded to the DOM, I cannot just add the listeners in my `mainWindow.js`. Is there a solution to this problem? And in general, is it a problem to have multiple js files for one renderer process, as well as multiple electron requires in those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

First of all in `mainWindow.js` I declared electron in a global scope with var:

```js
var electron = require('electron');
```

This made it available in the other script. I also added an onload event to the script to wait until the script was loaded. In mainWindow.js:

```js
// loading dynamic content here
callback = _ => { ipcRenderer.send('content:added', '') };
// script contains the script node
script.onload = callback;
```

In customerList.js:

```js
electron.ipcRenderer.on('customer:display', customer => {
  console.log('Customer: ', customer);
});
```

Then in main.js:

```js
// customerObject is a defined customerObject
ipcMain.on('content:added', _ => {
  mainWindow.webContents.send('customer:display', customerObject);
};
```

This finally calls the event in `customerList.js` and in mainWindow, the right customer object is logged.